# Practical Use For a Neuroimager

Tags: neuroscience, computational-modeling

You may be aware that neuro-imagers have become much cheaper and many are available with a SDK. I think this will open up a huge gateway for much more intimate human interfaces. However, I am stumped at the practical uses and whether the human controlled interfaces will be much better to the user. A mind controlled TV remote (for hospital patients) came as an idea, but once again, I don't think it has much practical use. Could any point me to any practical uses of this device? I am sorry if I am posting in the wrong section or this is a very opened-ended question. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Perhaps User Experience.SE would be a more suitable forum? http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What kind of neuro-imagers are we talking about? An fMRI unit comes at a couple hundred dollars, that's not what I would call "cheap". Also, how do you propose to take the step from imaging brain processes to mind controlling a TV remote? I believe there have been some successes in that direction, but anything I'm aware of is still far away from everyday application. Maybe you could provide some links along with your implicit claims, I don't see how this is every day knowledge (but then maybe I'm just especially uneducated).

Comment: @what: An fMRI unit for just  a couple of hundred dollars? Please let me know where I can buy that.

Comment: what is an sdk?

Comment: @Ana: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit

Comment: @what Thanks for the feedback everyone. I am a newbie, so what I probably used the word "neuroimager" wrong. I was talking about something like this: http://www.emotiv.com/apps/epoc/299/ Which seems much more rudimentary than the devices you are talking about. I am thinking that it is possible to connect this device to an Arduino and then to a TV to control it. But I'll post in UX to address a more fitting audience. Thanks!

Comment: @jsn There are thousands of publications on [brain machine interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_machine_interface). The possibilities are limitless, but pragmatically it depends on how well you can identify particular brain states. I suspect that if you post the same open-ended question on UX, it will get closed. I suggest doing some research and refining your question a bit. Good luck!

Comment: @H.Muster lol, that was a typo. "couple hundred THOUSAND dollars". Unfortunately I cannot edit my comment (bad programming here at SE).

Comment: You're allowed to edit your comment for a few minutes after posting, in order to correct typos and such. I believe the freeze after that is not "bad programming," it's a drama prevention device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of this question, neuroimager refers to a commercial grade EEG/EMG device. For example the emotiv epoch (considered a high end of what is commercially available) had 3 or 6 electrodes. The output of these electrodes is available to a developer through a software interface created by the manufacturer.

I believe that Jsn is seeking ideas of what can be done using this technology. I have completed a small iPhone app for another commercial grade EEG device - there is way too many artifacts from motion, muscle activity and poor device placement.

Practically speaking, it's a fun "toy" to play with, and it is very mobile, compared to a hundred electrode arrays.

Comment: That is exactly the one I was talking about. Thanks for the input.